# download multiple files as zip - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some URL of files. I want to download all the files as a zip file using JavaScript. Is there any easy way to do it?

Some files needs to be downloaded to create a zip file, which are those?

Answer (score 6):

This will get you started:

Download [jsZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and load it in your html.

Then in your javascript:

```
var zip = new JSZip();         

    //skip this step if you don't want your files in a folder.
    var folder = zip.folder("example");
    folder.file("myfile1.txt", "HELLO WORLD IN 1ST FILE"); //requires filesaver.js
    folder.file("myfile2.txt", "HELLO WORLD IN 2ND FILE");

    //...so on until you have completed adding files

    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
               .then(function(content) {
                //see FileSaver.js
                saveAs(content, "example.zip");
      });
```

Comment: In the last section instead of `zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})` you have to use `folder.generateAsync({type:"blob"})` because `zip.folder("example");` creates the new `JSZip` instance so `zip` object is empty but `folder` object is not